# how to create timeline in Elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, python, database, elasticsearch, time-series

I have a lot of post in elasticsearch and I want to display those post sorted, based on date and time and best performance is **time series**, do elasticsearch have a solution to this problem?
what is the best practice for this type of problem?
thanks.

I want something like this image:
[image]